# How do I start a program later if I unlock it from the Launcher on the left?

Tags: launcher

I'm a newbie from Windows XP. In WinXP if I deleted a program's icon from the desktop I could always find and start the program later from the Start>Programs menu. Is there an equivalent in Ubuntu?

14.04 is so far just wonderful. Will be great when someone gets Flash to work as it should and a few other things.

Comment: Hover your mouse over the icons in your launch bar, until you find one that says" search your computer and online sources" Click that, then type in program name in search bar.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, press the windows key (called Super) and then search for the program name. What you opened is called the Dash, to get it you can also click on the icon at the top of your launcher.

Have a look at [this](https://citizenweb.is/guide/linux/3-ubuntu) website, on migrating from windows. If you need, you could install lubuntu or xubuntu which are versions of Ubuntu that looks similar to XP.